# Keras LSTM always underfits

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to train an LSTM with Keras and Tensorflow backend but it seems to always underfit; the loss and validation loss curves have an initial drop and then flatten out very fast ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bqk0.png)). I have tried adding more layers, more neurons, no dropout, etc., but can't get it even anywhere near an overfit and I do have a good bit of data (almost 4 hours with 100 samples per second, and I have tried downsampling to 50/sec).

My problem is multidimensional time series prediction with continuous values.
Any ideas would be appreciated!
Here is my basic keras architecture:

```
data_dim = 30 #input dimensions => each timestep has 30 features
timesteps = 200
out_dim = 30 #output dimensions => each predicted output timestep 
             # has 30 dimensions
batch_size = 50
num_epochs = 300
learning_rate = 0.0005 #tried values between around 0.001 and 0.0003 
decay=0.9

#hidden layers size
h1 = 120
h2 = 340
h3 = 340
h4 = 120

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(h1, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(timesteps, data_dim)))
model.add(LSTM(h2, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(h3, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(h4, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(out_dim, activation='linear'))

rmsprop_otim = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=learning_rate, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08, decay=decay)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=rmsprop_otim,metrics=['mse'])

#data preparation
[x_train, y_train] = readData()
x_train = x_train.reshape((int(num_samples/timesteps),timesteps,data_dim))
y_train = y_train.reshape((int(num_samples/timesteps),timesteps,num_classes))

history_callback = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.1,
      batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_epochs,shuffle=False,callbacks=[checkpointer, losses])
```

Answer (score 0):

1. When you say 0.06 mse is underfit, this depends lot on data distribution. mse is relative term, so if the data is not normalizaed, 0.06 might even be overfit. In such case, pre-processing might help. Also, check if there is significant noise in the data.
2. Using 4 LSTM layers with large sizes means a lot of parameters to learn. Lesser number of layers might be enough.
3. Try non-linear activation in the final layer.

Comment: ad 3) The OP said they are doing a continuous valued prediction, so introducing a non-linearity would be at best a non-convetional thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your model only learns the weights of the Dense Layer properly, but not those of the LSTM layers below. As a quick check, what kind of performance do you get when you get rid of all LSTM layers and replace the `Dense` with a `TimeDistributed(Dense...)` layer? If your graphs look the same, training doesn't work, i.e. error gradients with respect to the lower layer weights may be too small. Another way of checking this is to inspect the gradients directly and/or to compare the final weighs after training with the initial weights. If this is indeed the problem you can try the following 1) Standardize your inputs, 2) use a smaller learning rate (decrease logarithmically), 3) add skip layer connections, 4) use Adam instead of RMSprop, and 5) train for more epochs.